# How do I update ad based on a set of data?

Tags: powershell

Im trying to set AD Title and Department based on a set of data and I can seem to get it to accept my userdetails  says object is not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$list = Import-Excel -Path "\\VRIDATA\HelpDesk\Scripts\Dan\Guardian.xlsx"
```

foreach($User in $list)
{

$display =  $User.Name

$dept = $User.Department

$title = $User.JobTitle

$UserID = Get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like $display } | Select samAccountName

$Userdetails = @{

Identity = $UserID

Title = $title
Department = $dept

}

Set-AdUser @Userdetails

}

Comment: Why destroy your rich ad object with the select statement?

Comment: I saw someone else doing something similar with trying to get the username from a displayname so i use the code solution from that.

Comment: I got it figured out thanks for your comment doug

Comment: Awesome. If you don’t want to delete your post, I suggest you fix the formatting for the code and then provide your own answer. After 48 hours you can accept it as the solution.